# Raspberry pi zero w MATLAB compatibility

Tags: matlab, raspberry-pi

Officially, MATLAB does not support the raspberry PI zero w. is there any way to unofficially utilize MATLAB to program for the zero w? Or, is there any estimated time for the zero to become supported?

Comment: It sounds like your problem is how to install a program on the Pi Zero, which is not a programming question.  This site is more geared toward the code you write for matlab scripts and functions, not usage of package managers.  I suggest that you ask at the Raspberry Pi StackExchange site... Unix&Linux and SuperUser could also answer questions about how to install software.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. If you start a question with "tldr", your question is probably too long and won't be read, you should redraft it instead! For a question to be on topic here, it should be specific, your entire 3rd paragraph and basically all of the 2nd paragraph should be removed as they are irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB 2018a supports Raspberry Pi Zero W.
You create a direct connection to PC using the Mathworks customized raspbian image. The hardware setup screens will guide you through the same.